# Displaying Other values of the row after getting the max of a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have is this query:

```
select MAX(C.Sales) as 'NumOfSales'
from
    (select COUNT(SalesOrderID) as 'Sales',
    TerritoryID
    from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    group by TerritoryID) C
```

right now it just shows the max of C.Sales
I want to be able to get the Territory of the max value.

Comment: Have a look at this already existing solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745635/2610061

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? You tagged both mysql and sql server and somebody removed one of them without having clarification. The solution is different for each DBMS

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL server Management. Also I figured it out using the solution that cars10m commented.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one record only, then the following should do the job:

MySql:

```
select COUNT(SalesOrderID) as Sales,
TerritoryID
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
group by TerritoryID
order by Sales desc limit 1
```

Sql-Server:

```
select top 1 COUNT(SalesOrderID) as Sales,
TerritoryID
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
group by TerritoryID
order by Sales desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Order by descending on taking the top 1 row:

```
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(SalesOrderID) AS Sales,
    TerritoryID
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
GROUP BY TerritoryID
ORDER BY Sales DESC
```

If you need all rows that have the same max amount of sales, it is more involved:
Here is a way to achieve this with some example data:

```
DECLARE @SalesOrerHeader TABLE 
( 
    SalesOrderID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    TerritoryID INT
)

INSERT INTO @SalesOrerHeader (TerritoryID) VALUES
(1),(1),(2),(2),(2),(2),(3),(4),(4),(4),(5),(5),(5),(5)

DECLARE @final TABLE 
(
    TerritoryID INT,
    NumberOfSales INT
)

INSERT INTO @final
SELECT TerritoryID, COUNT(SalesOrderID) AS NumberOfSales FROM @SalesOrerHeader
GROUP BY TerritoryID

SELECT * FROM @final
WHERE NumberOfSales = (SELECT MAX(NumberOfSales) FROM @final)
```

OUTPUT:

```
TerritoryID NumberOfSales
2           4
5           4
```

Comment: Or a simpler approach to get both rows with the same value would be to do "top 1 with ties". Then you would get both. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this if you want both C.Sales and C.TerritoryID:

```
select MAX(C.Sales) as 'NumOfSales', C.TerritoryID
from
    (select COUNT(SalesOrderID) as 'Sales',
    TerritoryID
    from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    group by TerritoryID) C
```

If you only want TerritotyID you can add this:

```
Select T.TerritoryID
from
    (select MAX(C.Sales) as 'NumOfSales', C.TerritoryID
    from
        (select COUNT(SalesOrderID) as 'Sales',
        TerritoryID
        from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
        group by TerritoryID) C
    ) T
ORDER BY T.NumOfSales
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select K.Sales, K.TerritoryID
from(select COUNT(SalesOrderID) as 'Sales',
    TerritoryID
    from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    group by TerritoryID) K
    inner join (
        select MAX(M.Sales) as 'MostSales'
        from(
            select COUNT(SalesOrderID) as 'Sales'
            from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
            group by TerritoryID) M
        ) MaxSales on K.Sales = MaxSales.MostSales
```

This the solution that I came up with after a little more research